# How to change status bar icon color Android 9 [Pie]

Tags: lineageos, 9.0-pie, oneplus-3, themes

I have a rooted oneplus 3t phone running Android 9 on a Lineage OS that I wish to style after the Fallout game franchise. I have many details figured out, except that the status bar color only seems to have the option of black or white. I would like the status bar icon colors to be green. This would especially be helpful as I've noticed that these white icons burn into the screen when a phone is old enough.

I first tried GravityBox which took forever to install only to find that they removed the status bar color tweaking features out of respect for other android releases that gave us this option by some other means... but Pie took them back.

I also tried Substrathum which gives an error page saying "Could not fall back to rooted mode. There are no other theme engines able to be utilized on this device at this current time." I found some sources which claimed to have it working on Pie, but their instructions were unclear or not specifically useful for getting past this error in Pie.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sub surely works, but v1015+ *requires* Magisk (LOS built-in SU will not work), and you will need to reboot after building your desired overlays for them to show up in the Manager section.

Comment: @AndyYan If you mean Substrathum, I did install it with Magisk. This issue of it being blocked despite being rooted is specific to Pie.

Comment: I have ~10 devices on LOS16 on my hand, and only one of them gives issues with Sub (and even then that's the device's fault). I know for a fact that Sub should work, unless yours is also a device with special traits...

Comment: @AndyYan I followed these instructions: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v9-0-0-beta-1-android-9-t3908768
to get gravitybox installed. Then these instructions to install substrathum:
https://www.xda-developers.com/substratum-hub/